# setting <option> for <select> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I am accepting a value through database. It is a select box with two options offline and online.

the problem is that this code doesn't work:

```
<select value="<%=app.selectedValue%>"> 
 <option value="offline">Offline</option>
 <option value="online">Online</option>
</select>
```

the value attribute of select is to be obtained from database. I use underscore's templating engine for the same.

I receive the correct value from the database but its not setting it on the select element. **Can anyone help me how I can get the value from database and then dynamically set the value to the select element so the proper option is selected?**

PS: I know about the selected="selected" attribute. The question is how i can use it dynamically.

PPS: Using this in an MVC structure using Backbone Marionette JS frameworks. So solutions with respect to that will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected value of `app.selectedValue` (e.g., what type of value is it -- option index, "online"/"offline", true/false, etc.?

Comment: app.selectedValue gives a string value of the selected option (offline/online). Also, if you see the code, i have specified the values for options. 
but if you think its better with index or booleans, let me know. If it works, I'm happy to edit it! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to take that logic out of your template and handle it within your Backbone view's `render` method (or Marionette's `onRender` event), e.g.:

```
// ... within the render() method
$("#out").html(this.template());  // render the template
$("#out").children("select").val(this.options.app.selectedValue);  // select option based on value
```

Sample code:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOwMPN?editors=101

Answer (score 2):

use this code it will work

```
<select >
<option>select</option>
    <option value="offline" <%if(app.selectedValue =="offline"){ %>selected="selected"<%} %>>Offline</option>
    <option value="online" <%if(app.selectedValue =="online"){ %>selected="selected"<%} %>>Online</option>
</select>
```

In other way you can use jstl tags to do the same

Comment: This works. but I also use key-value pairs in case there is addition of newer options. Then, the above answer is a hard coded one and won't work if any more options are added

Comment: that is not mentioned in question, please edit question, if possible??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know backbone.js but I think you should do like this:

I hope app.selectedValue is resulting either true or false.

```
<select> 
 <option value="offline" selected="<%=app.selectedValue%>">Offline</option>
 <option value="online" selected="<%=app.selectedValue%>">Online</option>
</select>
```

As we need to use selected="selected" in option rather than select element itself.

Comment: post rendering, if app.selectedValue = offline, won't this become    
<option value="offline" selected="offline">Offline</option> ?

shouldn't it be <option value="offline" selected="selected">Offline</option> ?